# Should highreps be allowed to delete criticisms of their own answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bug, deleted-comments, moderator-abilities

It's generally a common courtesy to give credit to other answers when you post a new answer that builds on top of the existing answers and/or comments.

Imagine my surprise when I see [an answer by a highrep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32579439/1122270) which not only borrows from my comments beneath my prior answer, but also removes comments in regards to the criticisms about his own answer, including my subsequent comment about the duplicity from my comments, as well as the fact that the OP already claims to have tried my suggestion (that this highrep has merely re-suggested (plus, only in an edit, after likely being pointed out by someone that his original answer made little sense, but that's only a guess, since only a comment `right, I updated it.` remains)) -- and such suggestion didn't even work, thus making his whole answer effectively fruitless.

I could, perhaps, understand that it may be ok to remove a comment if you address it in your answer -- which, as mentioned above, does appear to have also happened in this very answer, since, apparently, someone's earlier comment on this answer has likewise been deleted, based on the leftover "right, I updated it." comment by this highrep, but **what benefit is there to removing a comment like "the OP has already tried this, and it didn't work"**, without any clarifications on why such comment is removed?

***Is it really intentional that users with high score should be allowed to remove comments below their answer without any oversight nor notification to the commentor or the OP?***

***Is there not even any log where users can see which ones of their comments were deleted, and by whom?***

Comment: High rep users can't delete comments. (besides their own)

Comment: So, who deleted those comments, then?

Comment: @cnst Probably moderators after someone flagged it for some reason

Answer (score 22):

They didn't delete the comments, I did. They don't have that ability.

You left a comment claiming that someone's answer was copied and pasted from the comments on your answer. I found no evidence to support your allegations, and your comment was flagged by another user, so I deleted it. I also removed ones that referred to it.

Comment: more people should try suggestions that have been declared by OPs as not working?  maybe it'll eventually work for someone?

Comment: not sure how you could have missed it -- [it's right there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31877634/not-able-to-redirect-https-site-to-another-url-nginx-server-block/32579439#comment52972933_32474379)

Comment: @cnst - Plagiarism is a strong accusation. All I see is someone building an answer using some code that *may* have been based on what you suggested and some code of their own. They did not copy your words, and they added content beyond what appears in your comment. If you wish to provide a separate constructive comment explaining what you think is technically wrong with that answer, go right ahead. I just saw no reason for you to accuse that person of copying your work.

Comment: no, i'm done.  if you want people to continue to try suggestions that have already been tried by the OP without success, and of which i've warned through a comment you've deleted, it's on you.

Comment: So someone posted an answer that the OP already tried. It's not the first time that happens on Stack Overflow. When it happens, simply downvote, perhaps comment that it was already suggested and didn't help the OP, and move on.

Comment: Can someone clue me in on how exactly the plagiarism allegations fit in all of this? Is the OP saying that someone posted a suggestion, which the OP already tried, that was stolen from *their own comment*?

Comment: @Pekka웃, I did comment, but the comment was silently removed without any discussion or explanation.

Comment: @cnst you commented that someone had copy & pasted their answer from you.